# Missing Dependency: rdiscount

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, rdiscount

I am trying to build a site using jekyll, I have install `jekyll` and as the next requirement I have also done `sudo gem install rdiscount`

```
Successfully installed rdiscount-2.1.7
Parsing documentation for rdiscount-2.1.7
Done installing documentation for rdiscount after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when I try to start the jekyll server I get the following error:

```
 $ [sudo] gem install rdiscount
  Conversion error: There was an error converting '_posts/1970-01-01-placeholder-post.md/#excerpt'.

             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Missing dependency: rdiscount
```

Looks like it doesn't recognize the rdiscount,  I am on a mac and use homebrew to do package management. I am not familiar with the ruby or rubygem language (Come from python background). What might be the issue here?

Comment: How did you install ruby, with sudo or without? Try `gem install rdiscount` without sudo.

Comment: I installed with sudo

Comment: I am unable to instal without sudo because it give permission error.

Comment: You might need to uninstall gems and reinstall without sudo?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from some blogs. You can try this:

```
$ gem install rdiscount
```

to install this package and try to build the server again.

Comment: Came here from a google search. I know this didn't fix OP's issue but it did fix mine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the easiest way to ensure dependencies are correct is to use `bundle`. I thought this was in the Jekyll documentation but can't find it anymore. If you are already using this approach you will just need to add rdiscount to your Gemfile.

There is a guide on how to set it up for use with GitHub pages [here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages). Depending on your requirements the github-pages gem may be fine to work with.